# Time Series clustering: Changing warping window for Dynamic time warping

Tags: time-series, classification, dtw

I'm working on the same type of data and i want to classify the times series to find clear pattern of use.
My data is collected from clients of a telecom company, and we want to detect pattern of the amount of data consumed by clients with their wifi box. So each client have a time series of how much data he consumed each 6minutes (I resampled it to hours).
I also applied DTW with KmeansTimeSeries using `tslearn`:

```
km = TimeSeriesKMeans(n_clusters = cluster_count, metric="dtw", verbose=1)
labels = km.fit_predict(mySeries)
```

My question is i want to change the warping window for DTW in python, and i'm pretty sure it's easy think to do, but i just coudn't find a way to do it. I also want to find the best window parameter for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are talking about the tslearn package, we can have a look into the documentation of [TimeSeriesKMeans](https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gen_modules/clustering/tslearn.clustering.TimeSeriesKMeans.html).

The parameters are described in detail as:

> **metric** : {“euclidean”, “dtw”, “softdtw”} (default: “euclidean”) Metric
> to be used for both cluster assignment and barycenter computation. If
> “dtw”, DBA is used for barycenter computation.
>
> **metric_params** : dict or None (default: None) Parameter values for the
> chosen metric. For metrics that accept parallelization of the
> cross-distance matrix computations, n_jobs key passed in metric_params
> is overridden by the n_jobs argument.

So we can pass parameters to the metric. Lets then investigate the parameters that the [dtw metric](https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gen_modules/metrics/tslearn.metrics.dtw.html?highlight=dtw%20warping#tslearn.metrics.dtw) offers, where we find

> **global_constraint :** {“itakura”, “sakoe_chiba”} or None (default: None)
> Global constraint to restrict admissible paths for DTW.
>
> **sakoe_chiba_radius :** int or None (default: None) Radius to be used for
> Sakoe-Chiba band global constraint. If None and global_constraint is
> set to “sakoe_chiba”, a radius of 1 is used. If both
> sakoe_chiba_radius and itakura_max_slope are set, global_constraint is
> used to infer which constraint to use among the two. In this case, if
> global_constraint corresponds to no global constraint, a
> RuntimeWarning is raised and no global constraint is used.
>
> **itakura_max_slope :** float or None (default: None) Maximum slope for
> the Itakura parallelogram constraint. If None and global_constraint is
> set to “itakura”, a maximum slope of 2. is used. If both
> sakoe_chiba_radius and itakura_max_slope are set, global_constraint is
> used to infer which constraint to use among the two. In this case, if
> global_constraint corresponds to no global constraint, a
> RuntimeWarning is raised and no global constraint is used.

Thus, I suggest you call

```
km = TimeSeriesKMeans(n_clusters = cluster_count, metric="dtw", metric_params = {global_constraint:“itakura”} verbose=1)
```